# Issues with DocuSign API Example Not Working

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am trying to use the eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework-master example and I am running into issues.  I have put in all information that the config file requires, and yes I have put it in the correct locations.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to get it to work.

The issue I am having is in the code itself.  While walking the code line by line I have found that the error is on line 42 in ExampleBase.cs and I get an exception that says "{"-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY not found"}".  The Private key was copied directly from the DocuSign website.

Here is what I entered

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!--This is my API Account ID GUID-->
    <add key="DS_CLIENT_ID" value="xxx" />
    <!--This is my API User Name GUID-->
    <add key="DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID" value="xxx" />
    <add key="DS_TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID" value="FALSE" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_EMAIL" value="recipient email address here" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_NAME" value="recipient name here" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_EMAIL" value="{USER_EMAIL}" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_NAME" value="Charlie Copy" />
    <add key="DS_AUTH_SERVER" value="https://account-d.docusign.com"/>
    <!--This is my newly created Private Key for this example-->
    <add key="DS_PRIVATE_KEY" value="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
My Private key here
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here is what was asked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DS_CLIENT_ID" value="12345" />
    <add key="DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID" value="12345" />
    <add key="DS_TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID" value="FALSE" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_EMAIL" value="sue@example.com" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_NAME" value="Sue Cardella" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_EMAIL" value="larry@example.com" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_NAME" value="Charlie Copy" />
    <add key="DS_AUTH_SERVER" value="https://account-d.docusign.com"/>
    <add key="DS_PRIVATE_KEY" value="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----&#xA;
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAlrtiTEy3IzEI8jPuGXi/2C8KhNsJgyomP4XdXYwDjTyJm5u4&#xA;
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#xA;
9J1RReNa5OIWUf6ErbhNdANqlBYTqMAdXAkTzSsOtbOo15lvHH7V==&#xA;
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----&#xA;" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks all!

Updated Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!--This is my API Account ID GUID-->
    <add key="DS_CLIENT_ID" value="xx-xx-xx-xx-xx" />
    <!--This is my API User Name GUID-->
    <add key="DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID" value="xx-xx-xx-xx-xx" />
    <add key="DS_TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID" value="FALSE" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_EMAIL" value="test@test.com" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_NAME" value="Test Name" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_EMAIL" value="Charlie@example.com" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_NAME" value="Charlie Copy" />
    <add key="DS_AUTH_SERVER" value="https://account-d.docusign.com"/>
    <!--This is my newly created Private Key for this example-->
    <add key="DS_PRIVATE_KEY" value="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----&#xA;
<!--Several Lines Omitted-->
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----&#xA;
&#xA;" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for using DocuSign! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your own questions. Thank you.

Comment: See my updated answer. It's `&#xA;`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you entered the RSA Private Key as it was shown to you on the Developer's Sandbox Admin tool.

However, the C# App.Config file has a tough time when an attribute value needs to include `Linefeed` control characters.

The solution is to append `&#xA;` to the end of each line of the RSA Private Key.

**You** need to add those characters to the App.config file when you enter the private key.

The `App.config_example.txt` file included with the solution shows the result that you need to provide.

### Updated

Here is the App.config file I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="DS_CLIENT_ID" value="xxxxxxxx-65ca-4a6e-816d-ffxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID" value="xxxxxxxx-43f1-4184-944f-55xxxxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="DS_TARGET_ACCOUNT_ID" value="FALSE" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_EMAIL" value="larry@example.com" />
    <add key="DS_SIGNER_1_NAME" value="Larry Kluger" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_EMAIL" value="Charlie@example.com" />
    <add key="DS_CC_1_NAME" value="Charlie Copy" />
    <add key="DS_AUTH_SERVER" value="https://account-d.docusign.com"/>
    <add key="DS_PRIVATE_KEY" value="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----&#xA;
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEApfgRksDxB+rkNIsNA0ujDKT/9xZ7IFonKi9ejSCVqp6lCqZu&#xA;
B631QDSEzz3X1qfUsmBJfaydqU/YrV+vhKdd6NlP21aD+NuxHbB6i7ud9uRE1Sc9&#xA;
UGSkuXIcUYEISuR3WRnAFC64T34uEI8uIiXBJ7htbrHzU7qVHIvU0Jq6yv21wSWZ&#xA;
(Many rows are elided)
ci8nnQKBgHYyVpuxl5mLxAanH/WIuoM1NxV8STdzrRTpssbBSw+B/VPAfg3i88oL&#xA;
sJmumhoxvd6Z75BG9WS7ZYCVY+y/OsTNLvWx36UK5JIIfm57YYyqLv5LF2VyIM6j&#xA;
Es5tOkQv/IMo6jrMo9zxbVroCo5h8OIS+2Kt2dHJkM4TT4Ug97qe&#xA;
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----&#xA;
&#xA;" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Larry, unfortunately that did not work.  When I used &#xAk that threw an error inside Visual Studio with "Invalid character in a hexadecimal number 'k'".  I then re-tried the example that was in the example config file using &#xA; and that gave the same exception as without it "System.IO.IOException: -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY not found"

Comment: oops. Typo on my part. It's `&#xA;` (as shown in the App.config_example.txt file) cc @DWCoder

Comment: Since that didn't work, I pulled the private key out of the config file altogether and just stored it in the example for now for testing.  It now gets further but still dies in the same method.  Now I am back to my original issue I get DocuSign Exception! Reason: 400 Error Reponse: {"error":"invalid_grant"}.  It is dying in the method call on Line 42 in ExampleBase.cs

Comment: Are you setting the DS_CLIENT_ID and DS_IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID values? Note that the latter needs to be the guid for a user, not their email address.

Comment: Larry, yes I am setting the values.  If you look at the original post I am showing the config file from the DocuSign example and how I am filling it out.

Comment: @DWCoder, I added the file that I use. Some other ideas: 1. Check that the file is a proper Windows file (line endings are CRLF). 2. Carefully compare your client id, impersonated user guid, and private key with their sources. 3. After you make any changes to the integration key (client id), you may need to wait as long as 10 minutes for the changes to propagate throughout the DocuSign system,

Comment: Larry, I have submitted my updated config file so that you can see what it now looks like.  All information have been verified.  I am still having the same issues.  I am getting DocuSign Exception! Reason: 400 Error Reponse: {"error":"invalid_grant"} from the DocuSign Example project

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. I suggest starting with a fresh repo download. Or ask a colleague to watch as you go through the configuration process.

Comment: Larry, I have been able to move pass this hurdle.  With help from a colleague, I found that the config file actually wants the Integrator Key not the API Account ID Key.  I am now waiting from our contact there so that I can get Organization Admin abilities.